# How to efficiently parallelize a scikit SVM classification on a 2D image in Python

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, joblib

I'm using the scikit-learn package to do a SVM classification on an 2D image. Each pixel has 9 features on which the classification is based. Let's assume I have a successfully trained classifier `clf`, and I want to use it to perform the classification on that 2D image, i.e. a 3D array `input` (Xdim,Ydim,#features). In the most simple, but extremely inefficient way, this would be something like:

```
def svm_classification(svm_classifier,input_data):
    return svm_classifier.predict(input_data)

# Initialize output classification image
classified_image = np.empty([Xdim, Ydim])

# Do a very slow classification using nested loops
for x in range(Xdim):
    for y in range(Ydim):
        classified_image[x,y] = svm_classification(clf,input[x,y,:])
```

What would be an efficient way to speed up this process? In the example above, only one point is given to the classifier, while it can perfectly handle vectors (#samples X #features), so the `svm_classification` function should be used in a much smarter way. I was thinking about using 'joblib' and its 'parallel' module (https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html), but I'm not sure how I should do this on a 3D array. Is there a way to specify a chunksize for automatic slicing of the input data? Should I manually reshape the input array? I guess what makes that I cannot find the right answer myself is the shape of the input data (3D) which should result in a 2D classified image. Any suggestion in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding your description, but if you really are training classifiers on single pixels, i'm pretty sure, that this is one of the worst ways possible to do this. Without outputting these prediction-results to another meta-classifier, you have no non-local / neighborhood information at all, which is basically the most important characteristic in images.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been unclear. To stick to the issue itself, I assumed in the example that the classifiers were already trained on a whole bunch of training points. The question concerns the use of the trained classifier on new data. Does that clarify it better?